# How do I use foreach with my array in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, foreach

I have this array:

```
  var walls: Array[LineSprite] = new Array[LineSprite](20)
```

And I want to make is so that for all the items in the array between 11 and less than or equal to 19, the start is set to -2,-2 and the end is set to -3,-3.

To do that for one of the items it would look like this:

```
walls(0).setStart(-2,-2)
walls(0).setEnd(-3,-3)
```

How would I do what I want using foreach?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
for (i <- 11 to 19) {
  walls(i).setStart(-2,-2)
  walls(i).setEnd(-3,-3)
}
```

This translates to:

```
(11 to 19) foreach { i =>
  walls(i).setStart(-2,-2)
  walls(i).setEnd(-3,-3)
}
```